# How to sum several columns conditionally with pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to figure out a way to sum multiple columns but with different conditions in each sum.

This is the data I have in a dataframe:

```
order_id    article_id  article_name         nr_of_items price       is_black is_fabric
----------- ----------- -------------------- ----------- ----------- -------- ---------
1           567         batteries            6           5           0        0
1           645         pants                1           20          1        1
2           876         tent                 1           40          0        1
2           434         socks                10          5           1        1
```

This is what I want:

```
order_id    total_order_amount black_order_amount fabric_order_amount
----------- ------------------ ------------------ -------------------
1           50                 20                 20
2           90                 50                 90
```

This is how it would be accomplished in SQL:

```sql
select 
    order_id, 
    sum(nr_of_items*price) as total_order_amount,
    sum(case when is_black = 1 then price*nr_of_items else 0 end) as black_order_amount,
    sum(case when is_fabric = 1 then price*nr_of_items else 0 end) as fabric_order_amount 
from order_lines
group by order_id
;
```

How do I make the same using pyspark? I.e the thing I'm wondering is how to aggregate several columns but with different conditions.

I've prepared a pyspark dataframe in case anyone wants to give it a try:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

cSchema = StructType([StructField("order_id", IntegerType())\
                      ,StructField("article_id", IntegerType())\
                      ,StructField("article_name", StringType())\
                      ,StructField("nr_of_items", IntegerType())\
                      ,StructField("price", IntegerType())\
                      ,StructField("is_black", BooleanType())\
                      ,StructField("is_fabric", BooleanType())])

test_list = [[1, 567, 'batteries', 6, 5, False, False],
             [1, 645, 'pants', 1, 20, True, True],
             [2, 876, 'tent', 1, 40, False, True],
             [2, 434, 'socks', 10, 5, True, True]]

df = spark.createDataFrame(test_list,schema=cSchema)
```

I'm using spark version 2.4.4 and python version 3.7.3.

Comment: You can use the sum and when built-in functions to aggregate your data. In scala this would look like this : 

df.groupBy("key").agg(sum(when($"condition" , $"val").otherwise(lit(0))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Johanrex,

Here's a piece of code :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.groupBy("order_id").agg(
    sum(col("nr_of_items")*col("price")).alias("total_order_amount"),
    sum(when(col("is_black") == lit(1), col("price")*col("nr_of_items")).otherwise(lit(0))).alias("black_order_amount"),
    sum(when(col("is_fabric") == lit(1), col("price")*col("nr_of_items")).otherwise(lit(0))).alias("fabric_order_amount")
).limit(100).toPandas()
```

Output :

```
order_id    total_order_amount  black_order_amount  fabric_order_amount
1               50                  20                  20
2               90                  50                  90
```